# Can't update DataGridView from local database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have :

- 1 form

  - 3 panel ( 1 Left for menu/ 1 Top and 1 which fill up the other part of my page.

    - Several Control Users ( as much as the amount of button in the menu )

In 1 of the Control User i have 2 DataGridView. 
[2 Datagrid in the Control User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLSSH.png)

When i click on one of the row then another form open.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIXXs.png)

I got the data from my localhost database. When i load the program, no problem everything is updated.

When i click on "Validater cette paie" on the opened form, It supposed to insert this line in another table and delete the info of the table. PLUS refresh both of the datagrid( so the line i deleted from first datagrid should appear in the second one. And close the form.

The insert and delete works perfectly, and also close my form. But doesn't refresh.
If you noticed i got 2 refresh button, when i click on them it does refresh but i want it to be automatic.( otherwise confusing for the user)

```
public void BtnValidationPaie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string InsertPaie = "INSERT INTO paievalide(Prenom,AmiLocal,Extension,SBN,CheckIn,PaieHT,PaieTTC) VALUES('" + LblPrenom1.Text + "','" + LblAmiLocal1.Text + "', '" + LblExtension1.Text + "', '" + LblSBN1.Text + "', '" + LblCheckIn1.Text + "', '" + LblPaieHT1.Text + "', '" + LblPaieTTC1.Text + "')";
            MySqlFunctionEmploye.ExecuteQuery(InsertPaie);

            string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM newpaie WHERE ID =" + LblInfo1.Text;
            MySqlFunctionEmploye.ExecuteQuery(deleteQuery);


            AlerteControl AlerteControl = new AlerteControl();
            AlerteControl.MajDatagrids(); // **Calling the method to update DATAGRIDVIEWS**   

            //FunctionAlerte FunctionAlerte = new FunctionAlerte();
            //FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewNewPaie(dataGridViewNewAlerte); **This is actually the function i call in my method above. If i call the function right away i got an error saying my datagrid is Null, which can't be null all the cells are filled up.**
            //FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide(dataGridViewPaieValide);
            this.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("pas d'erreur");
        }catch(MySqlException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

---

Here is my method to call the function.

```
public void MajDatagrids()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Maj de MajDATAgrids"); **I checked if the method is called by this line and it is called.**
        FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewNewPaie(dataGridViewNewAlerte);
        FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide(dataGridViewPaieValide);
    }
```

I have been lookin for ages now and i can't find anything. Please also understand that i'm quite new with c# and Visual Studio ( Winform )

Edit : This is the code of the second form

```
public partial class InfosNewAlerte : Form
{
    public InfosNewAlerte()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=cap; user id=root; pwd=");
    public DataGridView dataGridViewNewAlerte;
    public DataGridView dataGridViewPaieValide;

    //
    // Au Chargement de la page, on recupere les infos de la DATAGRID-NEW-ALERTE et on les affiches sur le nouveau formulaire INFOS NEWS ALERTE FORMULAIRE
    //
    public void InfosNewAlerte_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblInfo1.Text = AlerteControl.id;
        LblPrenom1.Text = AlerteControl.prenom;
        LblAmiLocal1.Text = AlerteControl.amilocal;
        LblSBN1.Text = AlerteControl.sbn;
        LblExtension1.Text = AlerteControl.extension;
        LblCheckIn1.Text = AlerteControl.checkin;
        LblPaieHT1.Text = AlerteControl.paieht;
        LblPaieTTC1.Text = AlerteControl.paiettc;
    }

    //
    // En cliquant sur le bouton valider de cette page alors vous envoyez cette paie a la partie finance et la SUPPRIME de New Alerte
    //

    public void BtnValidationPaie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string InsertPaie = "INSERT INTO paievalide(Prenom,AmiLocal,Extension,SBN,CheckIn,PaieHT,PaieTTC) VALUES('" + LblPrenom1.Text + "','" + LblAmiLocal1.Text + "', '" + LblExtension1.Text + "', '" + LblSBN1.Text + "', '" + LblCheckIn1.Text + "', '" + LblPaieHT1.Text + "', '" + LblPaieTTC1.Text + "')";
            MySqlFunctionEmploye.ExecuteQuery(InsertPaie);

            string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM newpaie WHERE ID =" + LblInfo1.Text;
            MySqlFunctionEmploye.ExecuteQuery(deleteQuery);


            AlerteControl AlerteControl = new AlerteControl();
          //  AlerteControl.MajDatagrids(); // Appel de la methode de MISE A JOUR DES DATAGRIDVIEWS   


            this.Close();
            FunctionAlerte FunctionAlerte = new FunctionAlerte();
            FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewNewPaie(dataGridViewNewAlerte);
            FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide(dataGridViewPaieValide);
            Console.WriteLine("pas d'erreur");


        }
        catch(MySqlException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a method for refreshing the DatagridView. So after doing the insert and update, you can call that method to refresh the datagridview.  Also, you can use this method in your refresh buttons too.

Comment: Right right, that's what i have done.

Calling the method majDatagrid();

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call your method on loading the data in gridView at the end of your `BtnValidationPaie_Click`

```
   private readonly FunctionAlerte  frm1; //readonly is optional (For safety purposes)

    public partial class InfosNewAlerte : Form
{
    public InfosNewAlerte()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=cap; user id=root; pwd=");
    public DataGridView dataGridViewNewAlerte;
    public DataGridView dataGridViewPaieValide;

    //
    // Au Chargement de la page, on recupere les infos de la DATAGRID-NEW-ALERTE et on les affiches sur le nouveau formulaire INFOS NEWS ALERTE FORMULAIRE
    //
    public void InfosNewAlerte_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblInfo1.Text = AlerteControl.id;
        LblPrenom1.Text = AlerteControl.prenom;
        LblAmiLocal1.Text = AlerteControl.amilocal;
        LblSBN1.Text = AlerteControl.sbn;
        LblExtension1.Text = AlerteControl.extension;
        LblCheckIn1.Text = AlerteControl.checkin;
        LblPaieHT1.Text = AlerteControl.paieht;
        LblPaieTTC1.Text = AlerteControl.paiettc;
    }

    //
    // En cliquant sur le bouton valider de cette page alors vous envoyez cette paie a la partie finance et la SUPPRIME de New Alerte
    //

    public void BtnValidationPaie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string InsertPaie = "INSERT INTO paievalide(Prenom,AmiLocal,Extension,SBN,CheckIn,PaieHT,PaieTTC) VALUES('" + LblPrenom1.Text + "','" + LblAmiLocal1.Text + "', '" + LblExtension1.Text + "', '" + LblSBN1.Text + "', '" + LblCheckIn1.Text + "', '" + LblPaieHT1.Text + "', '" + LblPaieTTC1.Text + "')";
            MySqlFunctionEmploye.ExecuteQuery(InsertPaie);

            string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM newpaie WHERE ID =" + LblInfo1.Text;
            MySqlFunctionEmploye.ExecuteQuery(deleteQuery);


            AlerteControl AlerteControl = new AlerteControl();
          //  AlerteControl.MajDatagrids(); // Appel de la methode de MISE A JOUR DES DATAGRIDVIEWS   




            frm1.RefreshDataGridViewNewPaie(dataGridViewNewAlerte);
            frm1.RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide(dataGridViewPaieValide);
            Console.WriteLine("pas d'erreur");

           this.Close();

        }
        catch(MySqlException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So i moved those 2 lines where you mentioned it and still nothing.

`AlerteControl AlerteControl = new AlerteControl();<br/>
AlerteControl.MajDatagrids(); // **Calling the method to update DATAGRIDVIEWS**`

Comment: can you post your code of binding the data to your gridview

Comment: I have a class where there is the 2 functions to refresh the datagrid.( added the code under the comment )

Comment: i updated my answer. kindly click the check if it answer your question

Comment: Well now it says "RefreshDataGridViewNewPaie" and "RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide" Doesn't exist in the context.

That's why before i tried the same way with 

`FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewNewPaie(dataGridViewNewAlerte);`

But gives me an error of a NullReference

Comment: its because its on another class, see my latest code update, also can you edit your question and include your all code in 2nd form

Comment: form1 ( MainWindow) contain the 3 panel with all the Control User.

Control User (AlerteControl)  Contain the 2 datagrid

Class ( FunctionAlerte ) Contain the code to do the binding 

Form2 (InfosNewAlerte) is the second form which open when u double click on a row and close when you valide.

If i put form1, then i got "RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide Doesn't exist in the context."

And if i put "FunctionAlerte.RefreshDataGridViewPaieValide" then no error about the code but once i click on validate here comes the error the datagrid is null

Comment: you can trick, by after clicking on your button on 2nd form reopen the main form. note: remember to close the main form before going to second form to avoid many forms open

Comment: Problem is if i close the form1 then i wouldn't be able to reopen it cause to access to the form1 there is a user login. Which mean the user need to log in again hmmm not so practical.

Comment: Thank you for helping !!
The 2 lines you edited are the one who bring me no error in my code by if i click on the validate button then i got the following error.

`nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object` and the datagrid is null

Comment: have you try using my code ?. does it returns error? ow sorry bring it back. and also put the this.close at the end of your code just like on above, i think before you call your refresh button it is already close so it's not hitting that line of code

Comment: Yep just did again, to be sure and then nope. It says my datagrid has been null.
Cannot understand how it can be null.

I did moved back the this.close() at the bottom